# JSON organization of model

Tags: json

I have two competing thoughts on storing, what I consider, meta data for a record.

1)

```
meta: {
    dates: {
        added: {
            date: Date
            ,user_id: ObjectId
        }
        ,modified: {
            date: Date
            ,user_id: ObjectId
        }
        ,approved: {
            date: Date
            ,user_id: ObjectId
        }
        ,deleted: {
            date: Date
            ,user_id: ObjectId
        }
    }
}
```

2)

```
meta: {
    dates: {
        created: Date
        ,updated: Date
        ,approved: Date
        ,deleted: Date
    },
    users: {
        created: ObjectId
        ,updated: ObjectId
        ,approved: ObjectId
        ,deleted: ObjectId
    }
}
```

Can I please get some arguments in favor or against them?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these structures will matter only in extreme cases.

Eg:

- You need to access the data at a very high frequency
- You need to store few millions of these structures